# How can I see the LOG.debug output from CopyMapper of DistCp job in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, logging

I'm using a recent version of Hadoop with YARN, and after running a `distcp` job successfully, I'm trying to see the output of `LOG.debug` lines from `CopyMapper.java` and `RetriableFileCopyCommand.java`, but even though I've enabled DEBUG logging in `log4j.properties` (and of course copied this file to all the nodes in my cluster), I cannot see the output of these lines.

The LOG.debug statements I'm interested are:

```
LOG.debug("DistCpMapper::map(): Received " + sourcePath + ", " + relPath);
```

(from: [CopyMapper.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-distcp/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/tools/mapred/CopyMapper.java?revision=1619197&view=markup#l196) )

```
LOG.debug("Copying " + sourceFileStatus.getPath() + " to " + target);
LOG.debug("Target file path: " + targetPath);
```

(from [RetriableFileCopyCommand.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-distcp/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/tools/mapred/RetriableFileCopyCommand.java?revision=1596931&view=markup#l113))

The `distcp` job copies about 20 files from one cluster to another and reports success. Then I check the YARN WEB UI and see that job is listed under FINISHED jobs. When I click on that, `application_1454924704123_0001` in my case, I see only 1 entry in the list, such as

```
appattempt_1454924704123_0001_000001     Mon Feb 8 10:51:27 +0100 2016    http://hadoop10:8042       Logs
```

And when I click on the "Logs" I see that there's a "syslog : Total file length is 165516 bytes." And when I examine its contents I **don't** see any DEBUG lines (I see a lot of INFO lines), I also don't see any strings such as `DistCpMapper` or `Target file path` that should have been produced by `CopyMapper` and `RetriableFileCopyCommand`.

I also SSHed into `hadoop10` node, and did a `grep` but still couldn't find such DEBUG output, e.g.:

```
grep -r "Target file" /var/log/hadoop/
```

returns no result.

In my `log4j.properties`, I have lines such as:

```
hadoop.root.logger=DEBUG,console,RFA
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred=DEBUG
```

And in my `hadoop-env.sh` I have the following line:

```
export HADOOP_DAEMON_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,RFA
```

Is this not enough to see the output of all of the expected `LOG.debug` statements from all of the classes in `org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred` package such as `CopyMapper` and `RetriableFileCopyCommand`? Or am I looking at the wrong directory?

You can see the contents of my `log4j.properties` and `hadoop-env.sh` files at the end of this message, I made sure that they are the same on all of the nodes in the cluster.

`log4j.properties`:

```
# Define some default values that can be overridden by system properties
#hadoop.root.logger=INFO,console
#hadoop.root.logger=INFO,console,RFA
hadoop.root.logger=DEBUG,console,RFA
hadoop.log.dir=.
hadoop.log.file=hadoop.log

# Define the root logger to the system property "hadoop.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=${hadoop.root.logger}, EventCounter

# Logging Threshold
log4j.threshold=ALL

# Null Appender
log4j.appender.NullAppender=org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender

#
# Rolling File Appender - cap space usage at 5gb.
#
hadoop.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hadoop.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}

log4j.appender.RFA.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFA.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.log.maxbackupindex}

log4j.appender.RFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
# Debugging Pattern format
#log4j.appender.RFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n


#
# Daily Rolling File Appender
#

log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.log.file}

# Rollover at midnight
log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

log4j.appender.DRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern format: Date LogLevel LoggerName LogMessage
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
# Debugging Pattern format
#log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n


#
# console
# Add "console" to rootlogger above if you want to use this
#

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n

#
# TaskLog Appender
#

#Default values
hadoop.tasklog.taskid=null
hadoop.tasklog.iscleanup=false
hadoop.tasklog.noKeepSplits=4
hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize=100
hadoop.tasklog.purgeLogSplits=true
hadoop.tasklog.logsRetainHours=12

log4j.appender.TLA=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogAppender
log4j.appender.TLA.taskId=${hadoop.tasklog.taskid}
log4j.appender.TLA.isCleanup=${hadoop.tasklog.iscleanup}
log4j.appender.TLA.totalLogFileSize=${hadoop.tasklog.totalLogFileSize}

log4j.appender.TLA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TLA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n

#
# HDFS block state change log from block manager
#
# Uncomment the following to suppress normal block state change
# messages from BlockManager in NameNode.
#log4j.logger.BlockStateChange=WARN

#
#Security appender
#
hadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender
hadoop.security.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hadoop.security.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.category.SecurityLogger=${hadoop.security.logger}
hadoop.security.log.file=SecurityAuth-${user.name}.audit
log4j.appender.RFAS=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFAS.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.security.log.file}
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.security.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFAS.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.security.log.maxbackupindex}

#
# Daily Rolling Security appender
#
log4j.appender.DRFAS=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DRFAS.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.security.log.file}
log4j.appender.DRFAS.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DRFAS.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c: %m%n
log4j.appender.DRFAS.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

#
# hadoop configuration logging
#

# Uncomment the following line to turn off configuration deprecation warnings.
# log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation=WARN

#
# hdfs audit logging
#
hdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender
hdfs.audit.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hdfs.audit.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=${hdfs.audit.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=false
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/hdfs-audit.log
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.MaxFileSize=${hdfs.audit.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.RFAAUDIT.MaxBackupIndex=${hdfs.audit.log.maxbackupindex}

#
# NameNode metrics logging.
# The default is to retain two namenode-metrics.log files up to 64MB each.
#
namenode.metrics.logger=INFO,NullAppender
log4j.logger.NameNodeMetricsLog=${namenode.metrics.logger}
log4j.additivity.NameNodeMetricsLog=false
log4j.appender.NNMETRICSRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.NNMETRICSRFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/namenode-metrics.log
log4j.appender.NNMETRICSRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.NNMETRICSRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %m%n
log4j.appender.NNMETRICSRFA.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.NNMETRICSRFA.MaxFileSize=64MB

#
# DataNode metrics logging.
# The default is to retain two datanode-metrics.log files up to 64MB each.
#
datanode.metrics.logger=INFO,NullAppender
log4j.logger.DataNodeMetricsLog=${datanode.metrics.logger}
log4j.additivity.DataNodeMetricsLog=false
log4j.appender.DNMETRICSRFA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DNMETRICSRFA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/datanode-metrics.log
log4j.appender.DNMETRICSRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DNMETRICSRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %m%n
log4j.appender.DNMETRICSRFA.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.DNMETRICSRFA.MaxFileSize=64MB

#
# mapred audit logging
#
mapred.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender
mapred.audit.log.maxfilesize=256MB
mapred.audit.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger=${mapred.audit.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.AuditLogger=false
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/mapred-audit.log
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.MaxFileSize=${mapred.audit.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.MRAUDIT.MaxBackupIndex=${mapred.audit.log.maxbackupindex}

# Custom Logging levels

#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.audit=DEBUG

# Jets3t library
log4j.logger.org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service=ERROR

# AWS SDK & S3A FileSystem
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient=ERROR
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem=WARN

log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=DEBUG

#
# Event Counter Appender
# Sends counts of logging messages at different severity levels to Hadoop Metrics.
#
log4j.appender.EventCounter=org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter

#
# Job Summary Appender
#
# Use following logger to send summary to separate file defined by
# hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file :
# hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger=INFO,JSA
#
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger=${hadoop.root.logger}
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file=hadoop-mapreduce.jobsummary.log
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxfilesize=256MB
hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxbackupindex=20
log4j.appender.JSA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.JSA.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.file}
log4j.appender.JSA.MaxFileSize=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxfilesize}
log4j.appender.JSA.MaxBackupIndex=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.log.maxbackupindex}
log4j.appender.JSA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.JSA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress$JobSummary=${hadoop.mapreduce.jobsummary.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress$JobSummary=false

#
# shuffle connection log from shuffleHandler
# Uncomment the following line to enable logging of shuffle connections
# log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler.audit=DEBUG

#
# Yarn ResourceManager Application Summary Log
#
# Set the ResourceManager summary log filename
yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.log.file=rm-appsummary.log
# Set the ResourceManager summary log level and appender
yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger=${hadoop.root.logger}
#yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger=INFO,RMSUMMARY

# To enable AppSummaryLogging for the RM,
# set yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger to
# <LEVEL>,RMSUMMARY in hadoop-env.sh

# Appender for ResourceManager Application Summary Log
# Requires the following properties to be set
#    - hadoop.log.dir (Hadoop Log directory)
#    - yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.log.file (resource manager app summary log filename)
#    - yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger (resource manager app summary log level and appender)

log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary=${yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary=false
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/${yarn.server.resourcemanager.appsummary.log.file}
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.MaxFileSize=256MB
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RMSUMMARY.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n

# HS audit log configs
#mapreduce.hs.audit.logger=INFO,HSAUDIT
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HSAuditLogger=${mapreduce.hs.audit.logger}
#log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HSAuditLogger=false
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT.File=${hadoop.log.dir}/hs-audit.log
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p %c{2}: %m%n
#log4j.appender.HSAUDIT.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

# Http Server Request Logs
#log4j.logger.http.requests.namenode=INFO,namenoderequestlog
#log4j.appender.namenoderequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.namenoderequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-namenode-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.namenoderequestlog.RetainDays=3

#log4j.logger.http.requests.datanode=INFO,datanoderequestlog
#log4j.appender.datanoderequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.datanoderequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-datanode-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.datanoderequestlog.RetainDays=3

#log4j.logger.http.requests.resourcemanager=INFO,resourcemanagerrequestlog
#log4j.appender.resourcemanagerrequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.resourcemanagerrequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-resourcemanager-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.resourcemanagerrequestlog.RetainDays=3

#log4j.logger.http.requests.jobhistory=INFO,jobhistoryrequestlog
#log4j.appender.jobhistoryrequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.jobhistoryrequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-jobhistory-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.jobhistoryrequestlog.RetainDays=3

#log4j.logger.http.requests.nodemanager=INFO,nodemanagerrequestlog
#log4j.appender.nodemanagerrequestlog=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLogAppender
#log4j.appender.nodemanagerrequestlog.Filename=${hadoop.log.dir}/jetty-nodemanager-yyyy_mm_dd.log
#log4j.appender.nodemanagerrequestlog.RetainDays=3

# Appender for viewing information for errors and warnings
yarn.ewma.cleanupInterval=300
yarn.ewma.messageAgeLimitSeconds=86400
yarn.ewma.maxUniqueMessages=250
log4j.appender.EWMA=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.Log4jWarningErrorMetricsAppender
log4j.appender.EWMA.cleanupInterval=${yarn.ewma.cleanupInterval}
log4j.appender.EWMA.messageAgeLimitSeconds=${yarn.ewma.messageAgeLimitSeconds}
log4j.appender.EWMA.maxUniqueMessages=${yarn.ewma.maxUniqueMessages}
```

`hadoop-env.sh`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/opt/hadoop-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_OS_TYPE=${HADOOP_OS_TYPE:-$(uname -s)}

case ${HADOOP_OS_TYPE} in
  Darwin*)
    export HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.realm= "
    export HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.kdc= "
    export HADOOP_OPTS="${HADOOP_OPTS} -Djava.security.krb5.conf= "
  ;;
esac

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*
export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=/var/log/hadoop

export HADOOP_DAEMON_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,RFA
```

Comment: What I discovered so far: If you need to see at least some of the `LOG.debug` output from `CopyMapper.java` and `RetriableFileCopyCommand.java`, you need to pass `-D mapreduce.map.log.level=DEBUG` to your Hadoop invocation, e.g.:

`hadoop distcp -D mapreduce.map.log.level=DEBUG ...`. Otherwise no LOG.debug output from those classes, even if your `log4j.properties` has `hadoop.root.logger=DEBUG,console,RFA` and `log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred=DEBUG`.

Comment: I am running into the same issue where I want to print DEBUG logs from the S3AFileSystem.java. Did you ever figure this out?